# HTML form not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've got a very simple form on an HTML page I've done which works as follows. There are 2 buttons on the page "calculate" and "reset" The user inputs 3 numbers and when they click "calculate" it add's the values together and also calculates 1%, 2% and 3% of each number (and add's those values together too). The output is displayed in a table which looks something like this:

`input   %` 
`input   %`
`input   %`
`total total`
`calculate  reset`

Now my rather annoying problem is that I have replaced the buttons with images and since I've done this, once I click 'calculate' the values do not stay populated in the form and rather annoyingly in FF the page "refreshes" and skips back to the top too! What am I doing wrong? Here's the JS:

```
var sInput,dInput,pInput,inputTotal,sMonthly,dMonthly,pMonthly,sAnnual,dAnnual,pAnnual,monthlyT    otal,annualTotal;

function takeInput()
{
sInput=parseFloat(document.forms[0].txt1st.value);
dInput=parseFloat(document.forms[0].txt2nd.value);
pInput=parseFloat(document.forms[0].txt3rd.value);
inputTotal=sInput+dInput+pInput;
document.forms[0].spendtotal.value="£ " + inputTotal;
}

function isNan() 
{
    if (isNaN(sInput || pInput || dInput) == true) {
        alert("You entered an invalid character. Please reset the form.");
    }
    else {
        return(false);
    }
}  

function calculateMonthly()
{
sMonthly=sInput*0.01;
dMonthly=dInput*0.02;
if (pInput >= 300) {
    pMonthly=300*0.03;
}
    else
{
pMonthly=pInput*0.03;
}
monthlyTotal=sMonthly+dMonthly+pMonthly;
//rounded up numbers to the nearest whole number
//i.e. .5+
document.forms[0].supermarket.value="£ " + Math.round(sMonthly);
document.forms[0].deptstores.value="£ " + Math.round(dMonthly);
document.forms[0].petrol.value="£ " + Math.round(pMonthly);
document.forms[0].monthlytext.value="£ " + Math.round(monthlyTotal);
}

function calculateAnnual()
{
    sAnnual=sMonthly*12;
    dAnnual=dMonthly*12;
    pAnnual=pMonthly*12;
    annualTotal=sAnnual+dAnnual+pAnnual;
    document.forms[0].supermarketAnnual.value="£ " + Math.round(sAnnual);
    document.forms[0].departmentstoreAnnual.value="£ " + Math.round(dAnnual);
    document.forms[0].petrolAnnual.value="£ " + Math.round(pAnnual);
    document.forms[0].annualresult.value="£ " + Math.round(annualTotal);

}
```

And here's the code from the form:

```
<input type="image" src="calculate-btn.gif" onClick="takeInput();calculateMonthly();calculateAnnual();">

<input type="image" src="reset-btn.gif" />
```

Weird thing is, if I don't use images then the form stays populated with the output and the buttons work fine. Please be gentle, I am a total Javascript Noob.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the image button is acting as a submit button and posting the form to the server. Try this:

```
<input type="image" src="calculate-btn.gif" onClick="takeInput();calculateMonthly();calculateAnnual();return false;">
```

The `return false` will cancel submission of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Put an id on the numeric field you are interested in:

```
<input type='text' id='num1' ....>
```

Then in the javascript function `var num1=document.getElementById('num1');` And you can't be wrong. I don't suggest you to use the references you made, because if the form change (as you add another form), the references change.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your inputs to actual images

```
<a href="#" onclick="takeInput();calculateMonthly();calculateAnnual();">
    <img src="calculate-btn.gif" />
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="reset-btn.gif" />
</a>
```

Your other option would be to add `return false;` to the end of the onclick attribute.

Comment: Not good practise. The browser doesn't know they're buttons which, for one thing, will mean you can't tab to them using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your image acts like a submit button.

Add a `return false;` to your image `onClick` attribute!