# Real time updating of values on a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Slightly related to my other question (which was answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438579/html-form-not-working-properly), I was wondering if the following was possible (it likely is and very basic but I'm a bit noobish at JavaScript)!

So I have 2 input fields where the user types something into a form. They press "calculate" and then the function totals up what they have entered and then calculates 1,2 and 3% for each value respectively. It looks something like this:

`input 1%value`
`input 2%value`
`input 3%value`
`total total`

Is there a way for me to be able to update the form in real time? So by this I mean, as soon as the user enters a value into a field the function automatically starts updating the values such as total etc? How would I go about achieving this, can it be done purely in JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: Add a `onblur` event listener to each field that triggers your calculation.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all your answers, I'm going to give this a little bit of thought but all the answers on here have been good. Thanks

Comment: AngularJS (angularjs.org) is very useful in terms of data binding and handling many other tasks very easily and efficiently, you should take a look at it. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display 'realtime' (meaningly, as the user types) values, you can use the keyup values :

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp
  (for pure javascript)
- http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ (for
  jquery)

Comment: Thanks for this as this is exactly what I was looking for and have implemented. Now I just need to work on the isNaN function to stop it returning a NaN!

Comment: Actually sorted, I just needed to pre-populate the values with a '0'. Easy when you know how! :/

Answer (score 5):

Place an event handler on the `onBlur` event.  If you had a Javascript function called `calculateStuff()`, your input element could reference it like this:

```
<input name="something" type="text" onblur="calculateStuff();" value="">
```

The `onBlur` event happens when the user *leaves* the field.  If you want it to happen as they are still typing, you could use the `onChange` handler in the same way.

Comment: Awesome I will give this a try. Thanks both for your answers.

Comment: that wouldn't be realtime, that would be after they focus on something else, it should be `onfocus="calculateStuff();"` and in any case, inline JavaScript should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should call an onkeyup / onchange event in JavaScript to determine if the user has typed anything and inside the event just have it call a JavaScript function which refreshes the form by doing the math and inserting the values.

You can also add other event listeners such as blur etc.

It has been a while so i cant post any usable code but Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

Without building a complete answer for you here are some hints:

pure javascript would require something like this using the `.value` from an element:

```
alert(document.getElementById('elementid').value);
```

if you use a javascript library as for example jquery you can use something as [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

edit: you can use the [onchange](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_onChange.html) event to process the changes

Comment: `javascript as jquery`?? what does that mean? jQuery is a library that uses javascript

Comment: that was a typo of mine. meant "javascript library as jquery". updated that now

Answer (score 1):

Use  **onchange** event handler. Simplex code are given below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function summation()
{
    var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
    var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
    var total = (input1*1) + (input2*1) +(input3*1);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Total = $"+total;
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<p>Input 1 : <input id="input1" type="number"  onchange="summation()"></p>
<p>Input 2 : <input id="input2" type="number"  onchange="summation()"></p>
<p>Input 3 : <input id="input3" type="number"  onchange="summation()"></p>
<p id="total"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple! Instead of using the button, add an `onChange="your_calculate_function()"` attribute to each of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As to my knowledge you want to use

```
oninput='your_cal_func()'
```

Why `oninput`? It means same as on typing.
Why not `onfocus , onchange, onblur`, is because `onfocus` print on focusing on it, `onchange` will print on you enter or proceed (i.e. pressing enter button), and onblur will print when you focus on any another div

Therefore I prefer to use oninput