# Adding two numbers instantly using javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2008 for developing a webpage. The problem description is like this : I have 3 textboxes in the webpage one is "Price" second one is "quantity" and third one is "Amount". I want to get price*quantity=Amount.
I dont want to have any buttonclicks while doing so. First I am entering value into price then im entering value to quantity, as soon as I move the cursor out of quantity I want the answer printed in third text box automatically without button click. I want to do it in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441354/real-time-updating-of-values-on-a-form

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is the `blur` event, which gets triggered when a textinput loses its focus (if you click outside of it).

Bind it to your textarea like this:

```
price.addEventListener("blur", function( event )
{
    // do it
}, true);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egLzz5gb/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change` event on the input fields. This event is fired every time the value in the input is changed. I don't know what your `form` looks like, but this code should give you a general idea how to do it:

```
quantityInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
  amountInput.value = parseInt(quantityInput.value) * parseInt(priceInput.value);
});
```

If you're working with decimal numbers, use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`, be careful though, and preferably use `Math.round()`, as calculations with floating point are not 100% precise.

Comment: There is no `onchange` event, the event name is `change`. And since OP wrote "as soon as I move the cursor out of quantity", blur event would be more adequate.

Comment: I edited the event name in the original post. Thanks for that. `blur` would be fired once the input loses focus - that is, when the user clicks somewhere else. It's basically the same as `change`. I suspect, however, that `change` is fired only when the actual value have changed, while `blur` would be fired every time. It definitely wouldn't cause much trouble, performance-wise, but why calculate when it's not needed?

Answer (score -3):

```
Price: <input type="text" id="price">
Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" onkeyup="myFunction()">
Amount: <input type="text" id="amount"">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var p = document.getElementById("price");
    var q = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var a = document.getElementById("amount");
    a.value = p.value * q.value ;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `[onkeyup]`, it's obsolete.

Comment: `as soon as I move the cursor out of quantity` - onblur would be more appropriate

Comment: @Gothdo please do not tell me what to do ant don't. Those comments are not constructive.