# How to check several input's value real time?

Tags: javascript

**Description:**

I have three inputs: First name, Last name, and age.
I am looking for a solution if users type all inputs then show `validated`, and if one of them is empty or user deletes one of them showing `invalid`.

I try the following lines:

```js
$('#name' && '#lname' && '#age').keyup(function () {
   $('#display').removeClass('invalides');
   $('#display').replaceWith('Valid');
   $('#display').addClass('validated');
});
```

```css
.invalides {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.validated {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="lname" />
<input type="number" id="age" />

<span id="display" class="invalides">Invalid</span>
```

You may find it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rabiei/yh6bwtrc/)

Why do I use keyup?
In the following question, they offers keyup:
[Real time updating of values on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441354/real-time-updating-of-values-on-a-form)

Problem description:

1. It still shows `validated` after deleting the value of inputs.
2. it is not real-time checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check each input value on `input` event.

```js
const nameEl = $('#name');
const lnameEl = $('#lname');
const ageEl = $('#age');

$('#name, #lname, #age').on('input', () => {
   // if nothing is empty
   if(nameEl.val().length && lnameEl.val().length && ageEl.val().length) {
    $('#display').removeClass('invalides').addClass('validated').html('Valid');
   }
   else $('#display').addClass('invalides').removeClass('validated').html('Invalid');
});
```

```css
.invalides {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.validated {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="lname" />
<input type="number" id="age" />

<span id="display" class="invalides">Invalid</span>
```